# How to have tomcat 7 return its host name in custom return header

Tags: java, tomcat7, ubuntu-12.04

Our architecture:
tomcat 7
OS: ubuntu 12.04
hosted app - java web service

We have load balancer in front of several VMs, each of which has tomcat 7 hosting web services. When an http request is made via the load balancer we'd like to know which VM responded (for debugging purposes) by seeing that VM's name (or even IP) in some custom response header (like HOST header or something like that). We had something like this configured in IIS when working with Microsoft technology. We don't know how to configure tomcat 7 in a similar way. Do I need to set something in server.xml? I googled the subject to no avail. Any help will be very  appreciated.